# Setting up Wowza to transcode the audio in a stream to play using Flowplayer

Tags: streaming, http-streaming, transcoding

This is a real long shot, but I figure it can't hurt to throw this out here:

I have an IP camera that has an RTSP stream with h.264 video and G.711 audio. I setup a Wowza application (`myapp`) to use the `rtp-live` `StreamType` and then got Flowplayer with the RTMP plugin correctly playing the video. However, I believe the audio isn't being transcoded (it sounds horrible and I don't have transcoding on).

My `Streams/StreamType` in `conf/myapp/Application.xml` is `rtp-live`. I have the RTSP stream specified in `content/camera.stream`. That's really it, and it works, putting out a standard RTMP stream at `rtmp://myserver/myapp` with stream `camera.stream`.

So, I've been trying to enable transcoding of the audio while passing through the video, but everything I find (the [Transcoding Guide](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?304) and others) just confuses me more and all my attempts don't work, often with errors about missing SMIL files (I tried to [follow a guide](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?299-How-to-create-and-play-SMIL-files-with-streams-created-by-Wowza-Transcoder) but I might have missed something). I found one guide that specifically outlines [audio-only transcoding](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?347-Transcoder-Publish-h.264-with-Speex-from-Flash-11-to-h.264-with-AAC-audio-for-playback-across-clients), but of course I had no luck.

Is this the correct way to approach things? I thought it was and then tried to follow the [Flowplayer example for dynamic streaming with Wowza](http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/httpstreaming.html#example-with-wowza-http-dynamic-streaming-and-live-dvr) using the F4M and HTTP Streaming plugins, but no joy.

I think a lot of my problem is it's unclear to me what URL format I should use to reference my streams

```
http://myserver:1935/myapp/smil:camera.stream.smil/manifest.f4m
```

or maybe

```
http://myserver:1935/myapp/_definst_/ngrp:camera.stream_all/manifest.f4m
```

?

Any suggestions of where to start? What should my `Application.xml` and my transcoding template look like? Thanks.

Comment: In the same situation here, any luck?